# Error when using POST in AgularJS to .net WebAPI

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am currently having an issue with my AngularJS and my .net WebAPI. 
I can successfully get content or objects through my WebAPI, however I am currently experiencing issues POSTING data.

The errors that I get when trying to post the content is as follows:

> **OPTIONS http://localhost:18130/api/Products XMLHttpRequest cannot load**
>
> **http://localhost:18130/api/Products. Response for preflight has**
>   **invalid HTTP status code 405**

Bear in mind that when I try to post using Fiddler it works absolutely fine, no issues whatsoever.

The following is my AngularJS code I am using to post:

```
var data = { "Title": $scope.title, "Description": $scope.description };

$http.post(
    'http://localhost:18130/api/Products',
     JSON.stringify(data), {
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
          }
      }).success(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      });
```

Could someone possibly direct me to correct direction? Both WebApi and the AngularJS app are in separate domains, is this a CORS issue? How do I go around to fix when posting.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to disable `WebDAV` module in web.config

Comment: @Michael My web.config has no WebDAV in it whatsoever

Comment: it may be installed on IIS. I will post example config from shared hosting we have similar issue on.

Comment: Definitely CORS, search around on the web to enable it for web api. It was an evolving process for a bit, so you'll see different approaches dependent on the age of the article, but [here is a good starting point](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html)

Comment: @Michael I have gone through IIS and disabled WebDAv, but it makes no difference

Comment: You shouldn't have to call `JSON.stringify(data)`. I believe Angular takes care of that for you.

Comment: sorry, didn't noticed the part about different domains. you can try to use package from this example provided above or from [asp.net site](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) (i suppose the used method is the same).

Comment: @scniro I did try that but no luck at all. I have noticed that if I change the Content-Type from `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I get no CORS error but then no data is submitted so it triggers nullException in .net

Comment: What do you mean no luck? If you post your web api controller we can help you further. You shouldn't need to either stringify your data nor set the content type header - these concerns are taken care of for you (if you let it)

Comment: @Michael I have tried this and no progress at all. I have enabled CORS globally first then tried in the controller, but no luck

Comment: @Jordan I modified my answer slightly for you - also ensure the url is correct for your cors configuration

Comment: removed answer, sorry we can't debug the whole things for you - simply put - it's a cors issue - you'll need to research the rest, but the remainder of your problem is now fundamental to web api and how you are doing things

Comment: @scniro Okay I will have a go, but notice that the first error in the console has OPTIONS rather than POST

Comment: OPTIONS is part of the preflight request https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS. Use the browser's network monitor tool to see the request details -- it will help you understand what's being sent to and from the server and help diagnose what you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what template you used when creating your web api project, it may or may not use OWIN. *Assuming that it is* (if not, the other answer by scniro will be a betting starting point):

I had a similar issue when I was posting to web api from a js app. I installed Microsoft.Owin.Cors from nuget and in my Startup.cs I added:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        app.UseCors(new CorsOptions {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider {
                PolicyResolver = context => {
                    CorsPolicy result = new CorsPolicy {
                        AllowAnyHeader = true,
                        AllowAnyMethod = true,
                        AllowAnyOrigin = true,
                        SupportsCredentials = true
                    };                        
                    return Task.FromResult(result);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This will allow everything. In production you can change this to allow requests only from origins that you allow like this:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        app.UseCors(new CorsOptions {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider {
                PolicyResolver = context => {
                    CorsPolicy result = new CorsPolicy {
                        AllowAnyHeader = true,
                        AllowAnyMethod = true,
                        AllowAnyOrigin = false,
                        SupportsCredentials = true
                    };
                    result.Origins.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("YourAllowedUrl"));
                    return Task.FromResult(result);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should not be using OWIN for this

Comment: Ok no worries, I will leave this answer here in case anyone comes across this question and has had a similar issue when using web api with OWIN.

Comment: Hey Magrangs I have tried to install this and I no longer get the error I was getting, but no data is submitted! So when a debug every field appear to be null, any clues?

Comment: Okay, so turn out to be the answer for my question! I basically installed this package and added this code and it worked, plus had to do some additional changes. All good now. Thanks

Comment: @Jordan There be an issue with the data going up and it is not able to parse the json into a class. I use json.net, might be worth installing that and using that as your default serialiser. Alo I would need to see the post data going up in the console as it might be going up stringified.

Answer (score 1):

@Jordan try to disable all hanlers and then readd in web.config:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: I have just tried this and no progress! I have not even got much custom code, not sure why it is not working

Comment: have you tried to post a JSON object like @Lex has advised? just like this: `$http.post('http://localhost:18130/api/Products', data).then(successCallback, errorCallback)`